# Custom Labels in Packages - Potential BUG in Winter 19 (Confirmed as Known Issue by Salesforce)

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, customlabel, unmanaged-package

We have an unmanaged package using 167 custom labels to use the Translation Workbench in Salesforce and to be able to translate texts into different languages.

Until now, all our custom labels have been added implicitly to the package. I can't remember if they where shown in the package. But the package was uploadable from the developer org and installable on any destination org without errors.

Now when we upload the package, all seems to be fine. The upload proceeds without any error. We will get an install URL like this: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1v00000XXXXX (this is a fake URL only)

When we install the package on a destination org, we will get a huge list of error messages:

> Your request to install package "elastify BauCRM 2018 UMP 2.2 2.2017"
>   was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your
>   salesforce.com organization was affected.
>
> If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support
>   through your normal channels and provide the following information.
>
> Organization: dm118 (00D4600000XXXXXX) User: Uwe Heim
>   (0054600000XXXXX) Package: elastify BauCRM 2018 UMP 2.2
>   (04t1v00000XXXXX) Error Number: 708348760-16909 (-595487393) Problem:
>
> 1. An object 'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject' of type CustomLabel was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped
>      directory elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject: An object
>      'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject' of type CustomLabel
>      was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
> 2. An object 'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProjectCloseDate' of type
>      CustomLabel was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped
>      directory elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProjectCloseDate: An
>      object 'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProjectCloseDate' of
>      type CustomLabel was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped
>      directory
>
> ....
>
> 167. An object 'elfTBLabel_Token' of type CustomLabel was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory elfTBLabel_Token:
>        An object 'elfTBLabel_Token' of type CustomLabel was named in
>        package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

We use the labels all across in Visualforce, APEX and Lightning Components.

To be sure, I've explicitly added one of the failing labels into an APEX class which is part of the package like this:

```
String s = system.label.elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject;
```

Then I have uploaded a new version of the package and tried to install it on a destination org again. But the number of errors did not decrease by one an I still got this label-error again:

> 1. An object 'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject' of type CustomLabel was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped
>      directory elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject: An object
>      'elfBCLCProjectParticipantsMobile_SearchProject' of type CustomLabel
>      was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

This seems to be a NEW salesforce BUG in Winter 19.

Unfortunately I got now premier support and I am unable to report this error to salesforce via the support. they will close my case immediately - no matter if it might be a bug or not.

Does anyone of you got similar issues?

Is there any way or workaround to solve that?

---

**Update 3 (2018-11-06)**

This has been confirmed as a Know Issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HldP

**Update 2**

We have continued the investigation of this BUG. E. g. that we found, it is not caused by the labels itself: we can add the label in a different package via Formula, Page or Class and getting NO errors with the same labels during installation. And at the same time we can package the given Package and install it successfully after commenting out ALL the labels. All this research is eating up an incredible amount of time.

CONCLUSION: this proofs the labels for them self are OK. The package itself is OK. But ONLY package + labels AT THE SAME TIME ARE RESULTING INTO THE LIST OF ERRORS. So there is something, yet unknown, inside the packages which is fighting the labels. It is not simple to find out, because the package components are so many and they have lots of interdependecies so that we can't easily remove parts to drill it further down.

We have shared all of our investigations with the Salesforce Support and they told me to assign this Case to Tier 3 - whatever this means, it sounds good! ;-)

**Update 1**

We can say now, that this is not happening in general for any Custom Labels on any Org and with any Package. We have set up a new package on a new org and installing on an other new org. Using one single label which is used in one apex class. Result: uploadable + installable + no error.

So it must be something special with that org or that package which is causing this issue. Now we have to do an incredible amount of trial&error to drill down what exactly might cause that issue in particular. If anyone of you has tips in how to brute-force dirll-down such issues, any hint is welcome. We will try to create a new pack on the issue-org, and sub-sequentially add more and more metadata until we reach a point where it breaks. Hope we can nail it down within a reasonable time-frame. In parallel I've logged a ticket with the Salesforce support, hoping for their courtesy...

One tip in brute-force-drill-down such packaging issues is to have both, package providing and package receiving org on the same salesforce instance, in our case EU17. This will save an enormous amount of time because it takes several minutes for new packages to become available on different severs while they are available on the same instance immediately... more such hints are welcome if you have any. We have to do upload, install, delete, re-upload, re-install, re-delete many times over and over again...

Comment: Salesforce support should *not* be closing support cases where you can provide a GACK reference. Make your GACK of **708348760-16909 (-595487393)**  clear in the support ticket when you raise it. If they close it, let me know. I brought this up at Dreamforce last year and Salesforce were adamant that you don't need premier support to file GACK support tickets.

Comment: @DanielBallinger thanks a lot!! very good to know. In my experience the hard push to close even BUG reports cases is one of the top points undermining customer trust in the platform. At least they should offer something to pay-per-case and refund if it turns out to be a real BUG. But it's either Premier PLUS or nothing at all. It's not reasonable to buy Premier PLUS only to file BUG reports.

Comment: You mentioned you're building a package which suggests you may be an ISV. Do you have access to Partner Support? I've never gotten a bug report shut down on Partner Community.

Comment: @CharlesT yes we are on the partner community and unfortunately our bug reports get shut down almost always - which is imho not OK at all. Bug reports, repro, investigation, a-b-cross-tests and documentation are hard work which should be more valued by Salesforce.

Comment: Yikes. Honestly I've had largely good experiences with Partner Community. The worst was when I submitted a case to break a test package's connection to our LMA and it just sat there unacknowledged for weeks... the Escalate button was the magic needed to take it somewhere.